# Cassandra + SpringBoot: Configure Table to automatically add INSERT timestamp

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

Small question regarding Cassandra, with the context of a SpringBoot application please.

I am interested in adding onto the table the timestamp of when a row gets inserted onto the table.

Therefore, when creating the table, I do this:

```
create table mytable (someprimarykey text PRIMARY KEY, timestamp long, someotherfield text);
```

I can see a column timestamp, happy.

Then, the web application:

```
@Table
public class MyTable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private final String somePrimaryKey;

    private final long timestamp;

    private final String someOtherField;

//constructor + getters + setters
```

And when I insert, I will do the usual:

```
MyTable myTable = new MyTable(somePK, System.currentTimeMillis(), "foo");
myTableRepository.save(myTable);
```

This works fine, I can see in the table my record, with the time of the insert, happy.

Problem:
Now, for the hundreds of POJOs I am interested to insert into Cassandra, all of them are carrying this `timestamp long` field. Somehow, on the web application layer, I am dealing with a database concept, the timestamp of the write.

Question:
May I ask if it is possible to delegate this back to the database? Some kind of:

```
create table mytable (someprimarykey text PRIMARY KEY, hey-cassandra-please-automatically-add-the-time-when-this-row-is-written long, someotherfield text);
or
create table mytable (someprimarykey text PRIMARY KEY, someotherfield text WITH default timestamp-insert-time-column);
```

And the web app can have the abstraction creating and inserting POJOs without carrying this timestamp field?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't necessary to store the insert time of each row separately since Cassandra already stores this for all writes in the metadata.

There is a built-in CQL function `WRITETIME()` which returns the date/time (encoded in microseconds) when a column was written to the database.

In your case, you can query your table with:

```
SELECT WRITETIME(someotherfield) FROM mytable WHERE someprimarykey = ?
```

For details, see the [CQL doc on retrieving the write time](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__retrieving-the-datetime-a-write-occurred). Cheers!